# In GLSL integers are all 0

Tags: java, opengl, integer, lwjgl, zero

Strangely every integer that I pass to GLSL is 0, I sent an array filled with 2s and 1s but read all 0. The integers are sent to OpenGL for choosing a texture so I only get the texture coresponding to 0. Here is my vertex shader:

```
String vertexshader = "#version 330 core"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "in vec4 vertexin;"
        + "in vec2 textcoords;"
        + " in int yup;"
        + "uniform mat4 orthogonal;"
        + "out vec2 supertextcoords;"
        + "out int yup1;"
        + "void main(){"
        + "gl_Position = orthogonal * vertexin ;"
        + "supertextcoords = textcoords;"
        + "yup1=yup;"
        + "}";
```

Here is the fragment shader:

```
String fragmentshader="#version 330 core"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        +"out vec4 outcolor;"
        +"flat in int yup;"
        +"in vec2 supertextcoords;"
        +"uniform sampler2D texture1;"
        +"uniform sampler2D texture2;"       
        +"void main(){"
        +"vec4 texturev1=texture2D(texture1, supertextcoords);"
        +"vec4 texturev2=texture2D(texture2, supertextcoords);"
        +"vec4 final=texture2D(texture2, supertextcoords);"
        + "if(yup==1){final=texturev1; outcolor=final;}else if(yup==0){"
        +"final=texturev2; outcolor=final;}else{"
        + "final=vec4(0,1,0,0); outcolor=final;}"
```

The way I send the ints is

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribIPointer(2,1,GL_INT,0,(vertices.length+textcoord.length)*4);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length/4);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

10 numbers are supposed to be sent to OpenGL for a cube. 1 number per triangle(The back side is missing) to decide which texture for each size. Every second number is the same as the first so to make the textures equal. But only  texturev2 is ever used.The texure that I wanted for this experiment was vec4(0,1,0,0); because the number is a 2 and falls outside the mapped range. Why? If you need more source ask away.

Comment: In your VS you have `yup1` as an output but there's no corresponding `yup1` as an input in your FS.

Comment: @genpfault Please submit that as an answer and I will select it. Thank you! I will do it tommorow because I have to leave now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your vertex shader you have `yup1` as an output but there's no corresponding `yup1` as an input in your fragment shader.

OpenGL has no way other than exact symbol matching to link up non-block `in`/`out` declarations between program parts.  Un-linked inputs will not have anything particularly useful in them at runtime.

In your fragment shader change

```
flat in int yup;
```

to

```
flat in int yup1;
```

so that it matches the `out int yup1` declaration in the vertex shader.